# Can not convert RDD to sequence

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a variable `rawData` of type `DataFrame`. I want to get all the elements of a column and convert them to a Scala `Seq`.

```
val res = rawData.map(x => x(0)).toSeq
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(114, 40) value toSeq is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]
    val res = rawData.map(x => x(0)).toSeq
```

So `rawData.map(x => x(0))` is of type `RDD[Any]`.
How can I convert that to a `Seq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the exception said, the toSeq is not a member of RDD object. To make it easy for you. Take the command:

```
val res = rawData.map(x => x(0)).collect()
```

This command will return to you a sequencial object if you want to iterate this.